# FileNotFoundException during compaction

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

All of my nodes are throwing a FileNotFoundException during compaction. As such, not a single compaction (auto, manual) can finish and my SSTable count is now in the thousands for a single CF (CQL3).

*nodetool compactionstats* shows hundreds of pending tasks in each node but nothing is being processed.

Below is an example log of the exception:

```
Error occurred during compaction
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/cassandra/data/mtg_keywords_v5/keyword_organic_results/mtg_keywords_v5-keyword_organic_results-jb-31111-Data.db (No such file or directory)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.performMaximal(CompactionManager.java:281)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.forceMajorCompaction(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1935)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.forceKeyspaceCompaction(StorageService.java:2210)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/cassandra/data/mtg_keywords_v5/keyword_organic_results/mtg_keywords_v5-keyword_organic_results-jb-31111-Data.db (No such file or directory)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedThrottledReader.open(CompressedThrottledReader.java:52)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.openDataReader(SSTableReader.java:1355)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner.<init>(SSTableScanner.java:67)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.getScanner(SSTableReader.java:1161)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.getScanner(SSTableReader.java:1173)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionStrategy.getScanners(AbstractCompactionStrategy.java:252)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionStrategy.getScanners(AbstractCompactionStrategy.java:258)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runWith(CompactionTask.java:126)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DiskAwareRunnable.runMayThrow(DiskAwareRunnable.java:48)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:60)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$6.runMayThrow(CompactionManager.java:296)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/cassandra/data/mtg_keywords_v5/keyword_organic_results/mtg_keywords_v5-keyword_organic_results-jb-31111-Data.db (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.<init>(RandomAccessReader.java:58)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.<init>(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:76)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedThrottledReader.<init>(CompressedThrottledReader.java:34)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedThrottledReader.open(CompressedThrottledReader.java:48)
        ... 18 more
```

I'm currently in the middle of migrating 4.8 billion rows from MySQL which I do via sstableloader in batches of 1 to 4 million rows. Does the exception mean that I've already lost data and must repeat the migration from scratch? So far I don't see any stream error in my logs.

My environment is as follows:

- DSE 4.0.1 (Cassandra 2.0.5)
- CentOS 6.x x86_64
- Java 1.7.0_5x

**EDIT:**

Some additional info:

1. During the bulk loading process, I devised a mechanism to kill the sstableloader when the total progress reaches 100%. I also issue a "nodetool stop INDEX_BUILD" to all nodes. The reason for this is because sstableloader waits for the secondary index build to finish and this takes hours to complete (whereas the actual import time is just a fraction of the index build time). I figured out that the imported data remains intact after killing the sstableloader process and cancelling the secondary index build so I wrote a script to automate the mechanism. So far, I have completed more than 200 bulk loads with this trick.
2. I have paused the migration and restarted the nodes several times in the past week because the OS load reaches high levels (yellow or red in OpsCenter) after finishing several cycles of note #1. It's possible that a compaction is in progress when I restarted the nodes via *dse cassandra-stop* (yes, we are running DSE as a standalone process)

Could any of these be the cause? How do I get out of this situation? Manual compaction/repair doesn't work because they always throw exceptions. For repair, the exception is different but the meaning is the same - some sstable files are missing:

```
ERROR [MiscStage:2] 2014-05-03 00:42:10,386 CassandraDaemon.java (line 196) Exception in thread Thread[MiscStage:2,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Tried to hard link to file that does not exist /home/cassandra/data/mtg_keywords_v5/keyword_organic_results/mtg_keywords_v5-keyword_organic_results-jb-23797-Summary.db
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:76)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.createLinks(SSTableReader.java:1215)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.snapshotWithoutFlush(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1816)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.snapshot(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1849)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.SnapshotVerbHandler.doVerb(SnapshotVerbHandler.java:40)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: DSE 4.0.3 was just released with a much newer Cassandra version in it, can you see if you still have this issue after upgrading?
Also, if you don't actually want your indexes populated, I would suggest you just drop them, instead of canceling their creation.

Comment: It is safe to upgrade at this state of my data? (i.e. some files missing). Regarding the indexes, I actually want to have them populated BUT asynchronously. I didn't see such an option in sstableloader so I decided that I'd just cancel the index builds to allow me to import continously. Only when I've finished importing everything that I'll re-index the table as a whole.

Comment: Upgrading vs not upgrading shouldn't effect the "safeness" of your data.  Hopefully fixed bugs will make things safer.

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded the other day. After the upgrade, some of the Solr nodes failed to start at first attempt but managed to do so at 2nd/3rd try. I do not encounter the missing files exception anymore but I can't say whether it is the upgrade that really solved the problem. As mentioned in my comment to your other post, I did multiple passes of scrub + restart in my nodes and it seems to help a bit. There were nodes that eventually hit the exception again and that's when I decided to upgrade.

Comment: @PJ. how did you finally recover your cluster?  Facing the same issue atm.

Answer (score 1):

Have you dropped and recreated the keyspace? If so, it's probably this:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4857

Comment: No; but I truncated the table in question prior to starting the series of bulk-loads.

Comment: After truncating can you check to make sure all keyspace directories were removed from all nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Restart your nodes to clear the bad filename out of memory.

Comment: Didn't work. I tried doing a combination of scrub + restart. Most of the nodes were able to "move through" the file list but eventually they hit another instance of a missing file. Right now I'm repeating this cycle of scrub + restart + compact until I empty (hopefully) the pending tasks queue